# How to solve error "422:invalid authentication token" in Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, redmine, redmine-plugins

In redmine I am getting *422:invalid authentication token* and the logged in name is displayed with other user name instead of login user. There are no steps to reproduce. All of a sudden it occurs and it will be proper when I refresh the link. Please find the attached image for clear scenario.
In the attached screenshot login user name is Pavithra but all of a sudden the logged in name will be displayed with other user name (Highlighted in green colour).

[image: Error]

Comment: Have you tried to delete your cookies? Maybe it has something to do with the secret token? Do you have another Redmine instance? Is the other user at least a known one? What else might be worth to mrntion?

Comment: Other user is also a known one.I do not have other redmine instance.Ill clear the cookies and let you know.Thank you

Comment: I cleared Cookies.But again the problem occured today.Do we have some other solution for this??

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. It might help if you [create a new secret token](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/redmineinstall#Step-5-Session-store-secret-generation) (don't forget restarting the web server).

Comment: And do you have any plugins? Since you have tagged it so.

Comment: No No, I am not sure about it.I just thought if any plugins effect it or not.I am not sure about it.I feel the code is in application_controller.rb.

Comment: Well, then you should also list your plugins. And you should provide more information. "All of a sudden" means nobody has done anything? Or did the error come up with an update, installation of a plugin or whatever? Please edit your post and provide more information!

Comment: Recently I have installed the people plugin in redmine.If this is one of the reason then all users should get the same error.But this will occur for only few users(especially for one particular user)

Comment: The user should try another browser/machine. This might help.

Comment: Use this tip. It works up redmine 3.4.2
[stackoverflow][1]
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46212326/8607262

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue for several users. For most of them it was handled via a simple disconnect / connect operation.

But one of them gave me a hard time. It happened all the time with an easy step to reproduce : adding a new block to "my page" constantly resulted in the 422 invalid token error message.
No internet solution would give me a clue :

- cookie deleting
- secret key reseting
- forcing a redirect to the home page

Moreover it happened for any web browser, even a newly installed one. That led me to the *user_preferences* table in the database. I asked the user if I could reset his preferences and I did it with the following SQL command : `delete from user_preferences where user_id=xx;` where xx is the user ID.

After a disconnect / connect, a new block can be added to "my page", the 422 error is gone.